# Почему свадьбу играют?

Tags: фразеология

День рождения справляют, а свадьбу почему-то играют. Почему?

Comment: Я совсем не лингвист, случайно сюда забрела, но играют не только свадьбу, но еще и "играют в ящик". И, мне кажется, что на обоих событиях играют много музыки, вот отсюда и выражение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свадьба - обряд особый, и ни с каким днём рождения не сравнится. Свадьба относится к обрядам инициации (перехода из одного состояния в другое). Из других инициальных обрядов можно вспомнить роды, поминки, похороны, крещение, проводы в армию, и другие.  Все эти события, в отличии от *отмечаемых* ежегодных праздников справляют. Свадьбу тоже справляют, но кроме этого её ещё и сыграть можно,  причём почему "сыграть", действительно непонятно. Ни к какому другому подобному мероприятию, данный глагол не применяют, хотя "спектакля" там бывает зачастую даже больше.

Не проясняет дело этимология. Свадьба - это измененное *сватьба* (сватовство), тоже обряд не маловажный.

В "Домострое" (XVI век) говорится о свадебном чине, причём в списках, свадьбу только устраивают, но, если брать вообще, то по чину, что-либо справляют, а не играют. В словарях XVIII века свадьбу уже вполне себе играют. В XIX веке, по нацкорпусу, свадьбу "сыгрывают" уже гораздо чаще, чем справляют. Та же картина наблюдается и в наше время, но сейчас её уже зачастую и играют.

Сперва подумалось, что дело как раз в том, что от громоздких свадебных обрядов стали отказываться и вместо многодневных расточительных празднеств (справлять свадьбу), стали просто венчаться с незначительными вкраплениями обрядов (играть свадьбу), но версия не подтвердилась.

Судя по всему, тут мы имеем место с двумя явлениями:
 1. Десакрализация свадебного обряда, когда чин ещё справлялся, но сакрального смысла в него уже не вкладывали. Поэтому и получалось празднество-спектакль, где все игра, а не по-настоящему.
 2. На свадьбе весело. Кроме основного действа, естественно были и более локальные гулянья с песнями и играми. На поминках, прОводах, крестинах таких гуляний не было, поэтому их до сих пор только справляют.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу справить=играть. В современном значении, применительно к свадьбе, да.

Но не надо забывать, что устаревшее значение также справить=сделать: "Там ещё дела кой-какие надо было справить― поторговать, чайку купить" (В. В. Вересаев). Поэтому изначально, видимо, сказать "справить свадьбу" означало сделать акцент на самом факте бракосочетания, а "сыграть" - это уже речь о том, что церемония прошла весело, по всем правилам старинных обычаев.

Answer (score 1):

А почему такое разделение? Свадьбу и справляют, и играют. Это синонимы. Мало того, в словарях "играть свадьбу" даётся как областническое ( у Ушакова) и просторечное, иногда устаревшее, а литературного вообще нет( об этом событии говорят "отмечают день бракосочетания или день свадьбы", есть разговорное - справлять: СПРАВЛЯТЬ - 1.  несов. перех. разг. Отмечать по установленному обычаю (какое-л. событие).

http://my-dictionary.ru/word/10009/igrat   Играть свадьбу -(устар. и прост.)

Так что справлять = играть.И то и другое по установленному обычаю, т.е. проигрывается сценарий. Другое дело,что у слова "справлять" есть второе значение - 2. Приобретать (сниж.), а со свадьбой связаны большие затраты,покупки, поэтому часто, когда имеют в виду застолье, говорят "справляют", а про сам сценарий - "играют", чтобы оттенить смысл, видимо.

Comment: Справить - это отпраздновать по обычаю. Играть - делать, что-то не по-настоящему. Их синонимичночность в контексте свадьбы, как раз и смотрится довольно странно.
 Кстати, устаревшим и просторечным у Ушакова называется вариант "играть свадьбу", в статье "сыграть" выражение "сыграть свадьбу" даётся без всяких помет.

Comment: Играть и сыграть различаются только видом.У слова ИГРАТЬ 5 значений, не все связаны с чем-то ненастоящим(спортивная игра настоящая, сценическая игра - совсем другое). Здесь фразеологизм, связанный со значением сценической игры.Оно вполне уместно. Проигрывается сценарий, кстати, по установленному обычаю. Я не вижу повода разделять смысл выражений играть свадьбу и справлять свадьбу. Смысл одинаков.

Comment: Говоря, что справили день рождения, имеют в виду застолье,а в свадьбе важно и застолье, и сценарий, игра, ведь каждый играет роль. Потому её и справляют, и играют.

Comment: В современном виде, я эти понятия и не разделяю, хотя надо отметить, что "играть", без приставки употребляется, применительно к свадьбе, значительно реже.

 Было у меня предположение, о том, что значение их разделяли раньше, но не подтвердилось, поэтому свой ответ пришлось изменить.

Спортивная игра изначально - симуляция боевых действий или детское развлечение. Даже сейчас в ней есть куча условностей, без которых игра просто невозможна.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше  ( хотя  бы  в  19 - м  веке ) свадьбу  справляли  играя  сложный,  многодневный  и  многоролевой  сценарий,  гораздо  более  сложный,  чем  в  других  обрядовых  действах.  Может  поэтому  справить  свадьбу  и  сыграть  свадьбу  синонимы.  Эта  архаика  дольше  всего  задержалась  в  деревне,  с  чем  может  быть  связано  и  определение  в  Словаре  Ушакова  этого  выражения  как  областного.  Сейчас  свадьбу  тоже  стремятся  сыграть  по  сценарию.  Как  говорится  история  повторяется.

Answer (score 0):

"Свадьба, обряды, сопровождающие заключение брака",- говорит Большая Советская Энциклопедия. Вот, собственно и вся суть.